# Could you please explain what these words mean and transcribe them in Chinese script?

Tags: word-requests

> [image]

I need to insert the "typed-in" version of these words into my Word document (at work), but I know nothing about the Chinese language, and cannot type in Chinese.

What do these words mean? Please type them in, so I can copy and paste them.

I tried an online OCR service, but it failed..

Comment: '欢迎' means ' welcome'  https://translate.google.ca/#en/zh-CN/Welcome

Comment: For the future reader, please see: [How do I self-answer “What does this say?”](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/36144/how-do-i-self-answer-what-does-this-say)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word `欢迎` means [`welcome`](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqb=%E6%AC%A2%E8%BF%8E) and is typed as `huan ying`. This is a pretty basic word in Chinese so you can easily look it up even via a quick Google search.

---

#### In case you encounter a similar case down the road...

If you use macOS or iOS, you can add a handwritten Chinese keyboard, and write the character in the screen by handwriting it. Then tap on the correct character on the pop-up and search it via Google, or paste it on the dictionary (macOS has a default Chinese dictionary, for your information).

If you use iOS and download [an app called Pleco](https://www.pleco.com) (which is available in Android as well), you can use the handwritten feature and dictionary together via an In-App Purchase.